# What thing is consuming memory and isn't visible in ps output?

Tags: linux, memory

Free says that about 2GiB of memory is used:

```
[23:05:38] vvs@ratatoskr ~ % free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3919       2790       1129          0         35        687
-/+ buffers/cache:       2066       1852
Swap:         2109        153       1955
```

But the sum of used memory for all processes shown by **ps aux** is less than 1GiB.

The only mounted tmpfs contains 176KiB.

Where is the remaining 1+GiB?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `top`, and then hit `M` (capital m), to sort the processes based on memory usage.

If that doesn't help, if may be cached memory (even though `free` isn't showing it), i.e. memory that was allocated by programs and freed again, but the OS hasn't bothered yet with cleaning it up (because others programs haven't been requesting much memory).

Comment: top shows exactly the same result. Is there any possibility to find process which consumed that memory? It seems that s2disk is unable to free that memory/

Comment: It's possible that no application still has the memory in use, and that the OS just hasn't bothered yet to mark it as available yet, I think.